# Windows Server 2008 SMTP & POP3 Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smtp, pop3

This is the first time I have ever configured a VPS server without 3rd party applications such as Plesk control panel. I have got most functionality working in all my websites except I am very unsure as to how I can setup my email functionality on this new server.

Basically I want the standard `POP3` functionality, a bunch of accounts with private boxes, all able to send and receive emails using their individual usernames and passwords.

My server setup is pretty simple, its a VPS with `IIS` & `DNS Server` running. What I have tried to do to setup `SMTP` & `POP3` is adding the `SMTP Server` feature through the `Server Manager Console` (very unsure of the configuration as guides I found did not explain), I then installed a 3rd party application called [Visdeno SMTP Extender](http://weblogs.asp.net/hpreishuber/archive/2008/04/30/visendo-smtp-pop3-extender-for-windows-2008-server.aspx) as it claims to be a `POP3` service providing accounting and the ability to communicate with email clients.

That is as far as I have gotten as I can not seem to find too much information on the subject. So can someone please tell me how to go about configuring these services in order to provide standard `SMTP` & `POP3` functionality?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of free pop3 servers out there:

http://www.google.ch/#hl=de&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=open+source+pop3+server+windows&oq=open+source+pop3+server+windows

Comment: Yeah, it is looking like Visendo is fairly buggy and un-polished, can you recommend a good open source one?

Comment: Unfortunately not, many OSS mail servers come in linux flavour only :)